# Filter out terms that include any combination of F[X] and G[-X]

Tags: functions, function-construction, replacement, rule

I have the following problem which is closely linked to a previous question I asked some time ago ([Replacement rule for terms that are separated by operators?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191963/replacement-rule-for-terms-that-are-separated-by-operators)).

In this specific instance, suppose I have any arbitrary expression "EXPR" and I specifically want to set it to zero if there are a function F, `F[X]` and another function G, `G[-X]`.

GOAL: I am looking for a rule that realizes the aforementioned  situation.

Some Examples of EXPR that I want to set to zero:

1)`F[X]*___*G[-X]`

2)`F[X]@___@G[-X]`

3)`___F[X]@___@G[-X]___`

4)`___@F[X]@___@G[-X]___`

I literally only care if any term just has F[X] and G[-X] together in whatever setting or form.

BONUS:

A possible solution I thought of is the following

```
EXPR_ /; ! (Module[{X}, 
     FreeQ[EXPR, F[-X]] && FreeQ[EXPR, G[X]]]) :> (0)
```

but unfortunately FreeQ does not work in a module

```
Module[{Z}, FreeQ[F[X], F[Z]]]   Input
True                             Output
```

Comment: Does this work for you: `f[expr_ /; ! FreeQ[expr, _F] && ! FreeQ[expr, _G]] := 0; f[expr_] := expr` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it does not work because I specifically need F and G to also have the opposite arguments as stated F[X] and G[-X].

Comment: Ah, maybe this one: `f[expr_ /; ! FreeQ[expr, F[x_]] && ! FreeQ[expr, G[-x_]]] := 0; f[expr_] := expr`. tested with `f[F[Sin[x]]*G[Sin[-x]]]` is 0 because MMA replaces `G[Sin[-x]]` with `G[-Sin[x]]`.

Comment: Yes, this works at first glance but I am not really sure it distinguishes the x argument correctly that it is the same in both F and G. Try this for example f[F[X] G[-Z]] this is evaluated to zero when it shouldn't since they do not have the same argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this should work:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[expr_ /; Cases[expr, F[x_] -> x, ∞, Heads -> True] ==
 -Cases[expr, G[x_] -> x, ∞, Heads -> True]] := 0
f[expr_] := expr
```

Some testing:

```
f[kk[X]@F[X]@rr[X]@G[-X]] = 0
f[kk[X]@F[X]@rr[X]@G[-Z]] = kk[X][F[X][rr[X][G[-Z]]]]
f[F[X]@rr[X]@G[-Z]@zz[w]] = F[X][rr[X][G[-Z][zz[w]]]]
f[F[X]@rr[X]@G[-X]@zz[w]] = 0
f[F[X]@G[-Z]] = F[X][G[-Z]]
f[F[X]@G[-X]] = 0
f[F[X]/G[-X]] = 0
f[F[X]*G[-Z]] = F[X] G[-Z]
f[F[X^2]*G[-X^2]] = 0
f[F[Sin[X^2]]*G[Sin[-X^2]]] = 0
```